# How to use TFS (Team Foundation Server) on Eggplant?

Tags: svn, tfs, tortoisesvn, tfs-2015, eggplant

I've been trying to search how to use TFS and getting Repo URL.
Most of them saying I can get the TFS Repo from the URL link on website.

But when I tried clone/checkout repo on Eggplant, i'm getting "400 Bad Request"

1. Added TortoiseSVN bin on Preference -> Account -> Subversion Account
2. File -> clone/checkout repo : Selected "SVN" from the drop down Repo Type & entered the TFS repo (directly copy from website)

Anyone knows how to connect?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the issue you're encountering is that **TFS does not have SVN repositories**. It has two options: Git and TFVC. TFVC is a centralized version control system that is superficially similar to SVN, but *is not SVN*.

Comment: Hye, yes i realise that as well.. currently i'm trying to use git-tfs (https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs)  still having issues for now :(